# Database Schema Normalisation

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-schema

I'm attempting to model a database to hold (mostly) UK census record information. Would those with better understanding than me take a quick look at the following draft database schema and tell me if I have got the normalisation correct or if I've made any glaring errors?

[Census Draft Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dlxi.jpg)

I think it's relatively self explanatory but as I have not approached database design in many years, ignoring tbPerson & tbLocation, the thinking goes that I require the two link tables because firstly one person can appear in many censuses ... and secondly one census, can have many addresses. Is this draft design valid? Are link tables still the best way to do things these days??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General comments:

- The multiplicity relationships are wrong: most of the 1:1 are 1:n;
  the 1:n ones you've got look the wrong way round - surely 1 Person
  has n PersonCensus and you have 1 PersonCensus to n Persons.
- The Address and Location bit looks very confusing to me. You can't link a Person to an Address the way you have it.
- Within PersonCensus you have a Relationship, presumably to another Person. There is no way to link a PersonCensus or the Person it is owned by to another PersonCensus or Person.

That said, Link Tables are still the right way to do n:n relationships, and PersonCensus is perfectly sensible.

EDIT - Add Location stuff.

The problem with Location is that a PersonCensus is linked to one Location (which can have many PersonCensus' linked to it). Also, an Address is linked to one Location (which can have many Addresses linked to it). So you can go from a PersonCensus to their location, but then you have many Address linked to the Location. Which one is the Address of the PersonCensus? There is no way to tell.

If an Address is there for some other reason other than showing where a PersonCensus lived/worked/whatever at the time of the Census then I don't know what that purpose is and so can't make any further comments.

However if the Address is supposed to be linked to a PersonCensus then as designed it's useless. To link a PersonCensus to an Address remove LocationId from PersonCensus and replace with AddressId. Now PersonCensus is linked first to Address and then to Location.

Now I'm going to stop updating this as you really need to open up another question with a better description of what you're doing if you have more questions. Cheers -

Comment: Sorry, I should have added to ignore the relationship markers (1:1, 1:N etc.) I'm using Dia to draw up the draft and it adds them automatically. The Relationship table isn't functional in anyway apart from cutting down on writing "son", "wife", "head" over and over again at the moment, so I'm not too worried about it. As for the address and location, I still haven't quite worked it properly yet ... any suggestions to arrange it better?

Comment: Not without knowing what the difference between an Address and a Location is, what they mean in this context.

Comment: The location table in the database holds the names of towns or villages along with a brief description of the town/village and a longitude & latitude. The address table refers to a physical address such as a house or farm where a person lives. I want to separate the two as this seems the logical way of normalising that data. Does that make sense? So for example not having multiple address/house entries all with the same town location data replicated in each record ...